# redux how to use state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting an error on the following react redux code:

This redux index

```
const AllReducers = combineReducers({
    foolow: follow_Reducer,
    vacations: vacations_Reducer,
    register: register_Reducer,
    follows: follows_Reducer,
    isLogged: logged_Reducer,
});
```

This redux reducer

```
const follows_Reducer = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FOLLOW':
            return !state

        case 'UNFOLLOW':
            return state

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default follows_Reducer;
```

This react

```
export default function Vacation() {
    const vacations = allvacations();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('recents');
    const foolow = useSelector(state => state.foolow);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    <BottomNavigation 
        value={value} 
        onClick={() => dispatch((foolow))} 
        onChange={handleChange} className={classes.root} 
    >
        <BottomNavigationAction 
            label="Follow" 
            value="Follow" 
            icon={<FavoriteIcon />} 
    />
    </BottomNavigation>
}
```

That brings me an error

Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dispatching in a wrong way, dispatch should always be an object.
Try this code instead.

```
<BottomNavigation 
  value={value} 
  onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'FOOLOW', payload: foolow })} 
  onChange={handleChange} 
  className={classes.root} 
/>
```

After that you may need to do some change in the reducers too.

Comment: It works but now it doesn't do the action for me, He does not do updates the state

Comment: you need to add another case in the reducer for the `action.type case: 'FOOLOW'` and update the state there.